# Leak when setting MKAnnotation Title and SubTitle

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, mkmapview

I have a leak with the following code that builds up!  Why do I have this issue?  Is it due to it copying the properties inside the NSString.  Is there a way around this?

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *reg;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *reg2;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *altitude;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *heading;

-(void)updateTitles{

    self.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",self.reg,self.reg2];
    self.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ft %@°",self.altitude,self.heading];

}
```

The leak is 50% on each of the setting of properties inside this method.

**UPDATE**

Turns out this was being called from a block ultimately.  To try and work around this I did the following.

The following works but still leaks, clear now that self is retained.

```
-(void)updateTitles{
    __block NSString *thisTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",self.reg1,self.reg2];
    __block NSString *subTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ft %@°",self.altitude,self.heading];


    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_async(mainQueue,^(){
        self.title=thisTitle;
        self.subtitle = subTitle;

        [thisTitle release];
        [subTitle release];
    });
}
```

However that leaks and the following which should in theory work gives an unrecognised selector on the setTitle method!!!!!

```
-(void)updateTitles{
    __block NSString *thisTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",self.reg1,self.reg2];
    __block NSString *subTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ft %@°",self.altitude,self.heading];

    __block __typeof__(self) blockSelf = self;

    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_async(mainQueue,^(){

        [blockSelf setTitle:thisTitle];
        [blockSelf setSubtitle:subTitle];

        [thisTitle release];
        [subTitle release];
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you overriding the title and subtitle setters?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not using ARC, does the object that has the properties above have a `dealloc` method, and is it releasing the ivars correctly? Is this object itself being released by any objects that are retaining it?

Does overriding the getters instead of setting the title/subtitle make any difference:

```
-(NSString *) title
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",self.reg,self.reg2];
}
```

etc.

Comment: The object is active, and the values altitude etc are changing and are getting updated.  All dealloc is setup correct but that is not the issue.  Imagine calling the updateTitles 50 times, you'll see a big leak.  Oh and no ARC

Comment: How about overriding the getters?

Comment: No, then I get issues with it not updating properly as the KVO is not triggered.

Comment: OK, to debug try overriding the setters for reg, reg2, and firing a KVO notification for title... [self didChangeValueForKey: @"title"]. Just trying to see if the problem is with reg/reg2 or title itself.

Comment: I have just looked and it could be that self is being referenced from a block some place!  Need to try and sort that out I think as it is being retained too much!